# Return Json, but it includes backward slashes “\”,

Tags: .net, json, angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC 4 web api, here is my method to return the data.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetResults([Body] student params)
    {
        return studentSearchService.GetResults(params);
    }
```

here is the service call from angular

```
         function Get(){
          var Promise = $http.post('studentAPI/GetResults', params)
                .success(function (data) {
          // here backslash added to object
          }) }
```

this is what it looks like

```
   "{\"cid\":1,\"model\":\"WT50JB\",\"detail\":\"sdf??\",\"unit\":2,\"time_in\":\"2012-12-11T19:00:00\",\"time_out\":\"2012-12-12T13:00:06.2774691+07:00\",\"time_used_dd\":0.0,\"time_used_hh\":0.0}"
```

what am missing here ?

Comment: am I missing something here? Your method to `Get` data from the server is an `HttpPost` Verb?

Comment: passing input params

Comment: hmm, still seems off to me.  Either way, the sample code doesn't tell us where the `'\'` symbols are coming from... the `GetResults()` function is where that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you returning a json string from your web api?
It knows how to serialize objects into JSON's **automatically**.

Anyway to convert a string json into a json use `JSON.parse`:

```
var json = "{\"cid\":1,\"model\":\"WT50JB\",\"detail\":\"sdf??\",\"unit\":2,\"time_in\":\"2012-12-11T19:00:00\",\"time_out\":\"2012-12-12T13:00:06.2774691+07:00\",\"time_used_dd\":0.0,\"time_used_hh\":0.0}";
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);

alert(parsedJSON.cid); // 1
```

Comment: when I do this way it says cid is undefined..even when I log this in console still it shows like string

Comment: we dont want to do anything on the server side, that is the reason we are returning string

Comment: I just copy pasted my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qou8ocv7/ and it works. 
You wont miss anything - You should return a strong type object from your controller and leave web-api the serialization part.

Comment: ""{\"cid\":1,\"model\":\"WT50JB\",\"detail\":\"sdf??\",\"unit\":2,\"time_in\":\"2012-12-11T19:00:00\",\"time_out\":\"2012-12-12T13:00:06.2774691+07:00\",\"time_used_dd\":0.0,\"time_used_hh\":0.0}"";.. this how it is returned.When tried with the above in the example you gave, it didn't worked

Comment: Then you have a bug in your JSON generation - That json will cause you a js error on you client.

Comment: Amir Popvich: you mean problem is on the c# side ?? its not giving any error on the server side, data is returned from the server side

Comment: string str = ""{\"cid\":1,\"model\":\"WT50JB\",\"detail\":\"sdf??\",\"unit\":2,\"time_in\":\"‌​2012-12-11T19:00:00\",\"time_out\":\"2012-12-12T13:00:06.2774691+07:00\",\"time_u‌​sed_dd\":0.0,\"time_used_hh\":0.0}"";
Generates a compilation error on my end. Either you are not copying the right string or I don't know..

Comment: can we convert this string str = ""{\"cid\":1,\"model\":\"WT50JB\",\"detail\":\"sdf??\",\"unit\":2,\"time_in\":\"‌​‌​2012-12-11T19:00:00\",\"time_out\":\"2012-12-12T13:00:06.2774691+07:00\",\"time‌​_u‌​sed_dd\":0.0,\"time_used_hh\":0.0}"" to JSON object on the client side, is there anyway to do it

Comment: But that's not a valid string. Copy the line into your visual studio and in order for it to a be a valid string you will need to escape some " chars.